# How to install BURG on Ubuntu 13.04 with Windows 8 dual boot?

Tags: software-installation, burg

I've dual booted my laptop with Windows 8 pro and Ubuntu 13.04
Now i want to try themes on the grub2 because the grub 2 UI sucks :(

I've that BURG solves the problem for that

so can anyone help me how to install BURG in this dual boot case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to install `burg`

- Add to repository and install from there:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
  sudo apt-get update 
  sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
  ```
- While installing select `ok` (press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select `ok`) for each message. and select `sda` for `grub install devices` message. You can use <kbd>Space</kbd> to select the option.
- Update `burg` boot loader

  ```
  sudo update-burg
  ```
- Reboot your system.

**Here are some hot keys to customize Burg:**

```
t – Open theme selection menu
f – Toggle between folding mode
n – Jump to the next item with the same class
w – Jump to the next Windows item
u – Jump to the next Ubuntu item
e – Edit the command of current boot item
c – Open a terminal window
2 – Open two terminal windows
h – Display help dialog (only available in sora theme)
i – Display about dialog (only available in sora theme)
q – Return to old grub menu
F5/ctrl-x – Finish edit
F6 – Switch window in dual terminal mode
F7 – List the folded boot items
F8 – Toggle between graphic and text mode
F9 – shutdown
F10 – reboot
ESC – quit from the current popup menu or dialogue
```

It should work for you also.. :)